# Need fixed horizontal scroll on datatable when table is in view

Tags: datatables, fixed, horizontal-scrolling

I'm using datatables and I see it creates a div around my table for the scrolling when I use scrollX: true in my datatables initializer.

```
<div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="position: relative; overflow: auto; width: 100%;">
   <table id='myTable'>...</table>
</div>

$('#myTable').DataTable( {
        scrollX:        true
    } );
```

What JavaScript would I need to add to get this horizontal scroll to be fixed at the bottom of my screen when the table is in view instead of having to scroll to the bottom of the table to be able to scroll horizontally? When the table is not in view it would not be visible

Comment: How much data are you using (how many rows)? If it's not too many rows, you could use `scrollY:400, scrollCollapse:true, paging:false` in your options as well, then your table will always be 400px tall (or whatever value you choose), will have a scrollbar on the side if there are more than 400px worth of rows, and will have the scrollbar on the bottom if the data makes the rows wider than the parent container. This way, so long as you can fit 400px vertically in your current viewport, you will always see both scrollbars... If you need paging instead, though, it's likely going to be more work.

Comment: That is a fix. Though the person I'm making it for doesn't love the vertical scrollbar on the right for the table as well as the scroll for the page as a whole... We'll see if I can change their mind :)